# Can't connect to NAS, even via IP

Tags: ip, nas, synology

**Background**
Been having a *lot* if issues with this problem. Randomly PC won't connect to NAS for apparently no reason at all, while others it works. I read tonne of posts about various fixes, some worked sometimes, some didn't, but lately none did. Restarting PC, NAS, or router didn't work, nor did changing settings, checking firewall, antivirus, etc.. Finally I managed to figure it out.

Our nas allow us to make a network name to access it by, like `\\MyServer`, but sometimes when power goes out, or we have to restart router, this address won't work because the server's local IP had changed, and the address was still cached on our computer to the old one.

The reason can be one of many. In my case, it was none that I could find common answers to.

**TL;DR**
I randomly can't connect to my NAS via `\\MyServer` or it's IP `\\10.0.0.3`, but other PC's can.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Synology Assistant. This will find the NAS on the network if it is physically in range.

Then I highly recommend to use a fix IP address for the NAS. It is no good idea having servers with DHCP...

Answer (score 0):

**Reason (in my specific case)**
Sometimes the PC would only connect to the NAS via IPv6 *(almost feel like it does it on a whim)*, IPv4 won't work at all. That or the old IP is cached on your system.

IPv4 looks something like one of these: `10.0.0.5`, `172.16.0.2`, or `192.168.0.0`
IPv6 looks something like: `fe80::842a:a43d:3123:1332`

**Quick fix attempt first**
First, just try opening command prompt and enter `ipconfig /flushdns`, then try to connect to your usual `\\MyServer` address, see if that works now.

**Didn't work?**
What you can try is to see if you can connect via its IPv6 — but first you need to somehow obtain it.

**Step 1** In command prompt, type `ping MyServer` *(replaced with whatever name you have)*, and it see if it manages to ping it. If it does, it will resolve the IP and show an IPv6. If it shows IPv4 or can't connect at all, see further down.
**Step 2** Locate the IPv6 at the top, remove `%` and number after.
**Step 3** Replace `:` with `-`. Note doubles if you have that: `::` with `--`.
**Step 4**  Prefix the usual `\\` at the start, and add `.ipv6-literal.net` at the end. Now try to connect to the server using that. With the IPv6 example above, it'd be something like: `\\fe80--842a-a43d-3123-1332.ipv6-literal.net`

**Ping shows IPv4?**
Try to ping with one of the other computers, or if you are able to, login to the web dashboard or equivalent on one of those computers, and see if you can find any information about the server's IP's, with goal of finding its IPv6.

Once found, do steps above.

### Done!

**Other stuff:**

**IPv6 in browser** — remove the `%` and number, put IP inside brackets `[]` and then connect. Example: `http://[fe80::842a:a43d:3123:1332]`.

**Creating alias of the weird IPv6**:
**Step 1** Right click Notepad, and open as Administrator
**Step 2** Go to File → Open, change the dropdown above 'open' from `Textfiles (*.txt)` to `All files (*.*)`.
**Step 3** Locate the `hosts` file, located at `C:\C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` and open
**Step 4** At the bottom, write the IPv6 with the colons AND the `%##`, then a space, then the alias you want it to use (case insensitive). Example: `fe80::842a:a43d:3123:1332%15 MyAlias` and save. You should now be able to use `\\MyAlias` to connect to it.

**NOTE** The `%##` number is unique to each computer. E.g. your computer gets `%15`, the next get `%7`. The rest of the IP is identical. To get the `%##` number of a different PC, write `ipconfig` in its command prompt. It should list its own IPv6 with its appended `%##` at the end.
**Another note:** If you need to change an IP in the hosts file of an IP that no longer work, you also need to use `ipconfig /flushdns` again.